# null instead of ==

Tags: haskell, coding-style, operators, typeclass

I have just started to learn Haskell out of interest. I follow [learnyouahaskell.com](http://learnyouahaskell.com).

There I found this:

> `null` checks if a list is empty. If it
>   is, it returns `True`, otherwise it
>   returns `False`. Use this function
>   instead of `xs == []` (if you have a
>   list called `xs`)

Why is that? Why should we use `null` instead of `==` when both produce the same result?

Thanks.

Comment: Excellent question BTW. The thought had not yet crossed my mind. (Still learning Haskell too)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Comparing the lists with `==` requires elements to be comparable (denoted as `Eq a`).

```
Prelude> :t (==[])
(==[]) :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
```

For example, `[sin] == []` won't work, since you can't compare functions. It might seem stupid, but the type system must judge type of an expression without looking at its value.

An alternate check would be `length xs == 0`, this doesn't require equality but won't stop if your list is infinite (try `length [1..] == 0`). That's why there's a dedicated function.

```
null [] = True
null _ = False

Prelude> :t null
null :: [a] -> Bool     -- Notice lack of (Eq a).
```

Answer (score 11):

In my opinion, `null myList` reads more naturally than `myList == []`.

But the *raison d'être* for `null` is that it can be used as a function. For example, here's a function that takes a list of lists, and returns only the nonempty ones:

```
nonemptyLists :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
nonemptyLists = filter (not . null)
```

Without `null`, this would be more awkward:

```
nonEmptyLists = filter ([] /=)
```

Comment: How can inverse the operands and it ready even more naturally: `filter (/= [])`. Note that I'd always prefer pattern matching over an equality operator (unless in the above case of using it as a function)

Comment: See sdcvvc's answer: The real reason is that `null` works with any list, while `(== [])` only works with lists of `Eq`.

Comment: @KennyTM: Of course, fixed. Thanks. @Piet Delport: That hadn't occurred to me. @sdcvvc: +1 :)

Comment: Wouldn't `(/= [])` be more natural? (Well, unless you like yoda-conditions. :) )

Comment: Probably. The point was to demonstrate awkwardness though, eh? ;)

Answer (score 6):

Another benefit to using `null` is that many other containers (e.g. Data.Sequence, Data.ByteString, etc.) have a `null` function as well.  This makes it easy to switch to another implementation simply by changing your import statements.