# Translating a piece of Java code to Haskell

Tags: java, haskell

I am solving the [Baby Blocks](http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/fun/projects/blocks/blocks.html) problem. I have a peice of java code that I want to translate to Haskell:

Java:

```
for (int i = 1; i <optHeight.length ; i++) {
    int maxHeightIndex = 0;
        for (int j = i-1; j >=0 ; j--) {
            // Need help from here
            if(boxes[j].width>boxes[i-1].width && boxes[j].depth>boxes[i-1].depth) {
                if(optHeight[maxHeightIndex]<optHeight[j+1]) { <-- How do I write this condition
                    maxHeightIndex = j+1;
                }
            }
        }
        optHeight[i]=optHeight[maxHeightIndex] + boxes[i-1].height;
}
```

where `optHeight` is a 1-D array and `boxes` is an object consiting of `height, width, depth` as data members. In Haskell, it is just a list of list. Due to lack of mutable arrays / variables, I am totally helpless.

Haskell:

```
b list = do
 forM_ [1..length list] $ \i -> do
  let maxHeight = 0
  forM_ [0..(i-1)] $ \j  -> do
   if list!!j!!1 > list!!i-1!!1 && list!!j!!2 > list !!j!!2 then
    maxHeight = j + 1
```

PS: I am totally a beginner in Haskell

Comment: Stop trying to write procedural Haskell. Instead of mutation, think about sequences of transformations of values.

Comment: Is your Java code working? The comment in it seems to be suggesting otherwise. :)

Comment: Writing in language X by translating from language Y is one of the worst ways, almost always producing very unidiomatic code. Express your algorithm using what Haskell offers instead of trying to translate from another language.

Comment: @Caleth, Actually, I am kind of time constrained and I don't have the required expertise. Can you please help me out in finding an alternative?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way to solve this problem (I think), is to consider every rotation of every box (so you have `3n` total rotations). Then, you order these based on increasing size of their base. The problem then is just to pick the longest subsequence of boxes that "fit" with each other (you don't need to worry about picking the same box twice because a box could never fit on itself). This sounds a lot like the canonical [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) problem, which suggests we will want a dynamic programming solution. We will have an array of length `3n` where the ith element represents the maximum height of the stack you can make with the ith box at the top.

```
maxHeight(i) = { height(i) + max[ maxHeight(j) ] such that
                 width(j) > width(i), depth(j) > depth(i), 0 <= j < i }
```

Now, lets get started on the Haskell solution. I will assume your input is a list of the dimensions. Notice how closely the code mirrors the solution I described - the trick is to write things declaratively.

```hs
import Data.List (sortOn)
import Data.Vector (fromList, (!), generate)
import Data.Ord (Down(..))

babyBlocks :: [(Int,Int,Int)] -> Int
babyBlocks blocks = maxHeights ! (3*n - 1)
  where
    -- get the number of blocks
    n = length blocks

    -- generate the `3n` blocks formed by rotating the existing blocks,
    -- sort them by their base size, and store them in a vector for
    -- fast retrieval
    sortedBlocks = fromList
                 . sortOn (\(x,y,z) -> Down (x*y))
                 . concatMap (\(x,y,z) -> [(x,y,z),(y,z,x),(z,x,y)])
                 $ blocks

    -- we'll make ourselves a couple helper functions, just so
    -- our translation of the recurrence relation looks better
    height n    = let (_,_,z) = sortedBlocks ! n in z
    width n     = let (_,y,_) = sortedBlocks ! n in y
    depth n     = let (x,_,_) = sortedBlocks ! n in x
    maxHeight n = maxHeights ! n

    -- state the dynamic programming
    maxHeights = generate (3*n) (\i ->
                   height i + maximum (0 : [ maxHeight j | j<-[0..(i-1)]
                                                         , width j > width i
                                                         , depth j > depth i ]))
```

The part you seemed to be having trouble with is the dynamic programming in the last part. Because Haskell is lazy, it is actually completely OK for me to use `maxHeight` while defining `maxHeights`, even if I don't know what order my vector is going to be initialized in!

Comment: Note that this answer is not fully correct. `babyBlocks [(3,3,1), (2,2,5), (2,2,2)]` should not return 5.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved in a very readable way by composing very simple functions to find the overall solution. A possible strategy is as follows:

1. Take all the available blocks and declare them as an initial set of towers.
2. Combine each tower with each available block (if possible). This results in a new set of towers.
3. Repeat step 2 until the set of towers does not change anymore.
4. Extract the tower of the set which is the highest.

The corresponding code is as follows (explanation below):

```
type Block = (Int,Int,Int)
type Tower = [Block]

babyBlocks :: [Block] -> Int
babyBlocks blocks = highest $ converge allBlocks initialTowers
    where allBlocks = possibleBlocks blocks
          initialTowers = map (:[]) allBlocks

possibleBlocks :: [Block] -> [Block]
possibleBlocks = concatMap (\(w,d,h) -> [(w,d,h),(w,h,d),(d,h,w)])

canStack :: Block -> Block -> Bool
canStack (w1,d1,_) (w2,d2,_) = w2 < w1 && d2 < d1 || w2 < d1 && d2 < w1

expand :: Tower -> [Block] -> [Tower]
expand tower@(top:_) = map (:tower) . filter (canStack top)

converge :: [Block] -> [Tower] -> [Tower]
converge blocks towers | null newTowers = towers
                       | otherwise = converge blocks newTowers
    where newTowers = concatMap (flip expand blocks) towers

height :: Tower -> Int
height = sum . map (\(_,_,h) -> h)

highest :: [Tower] -> Int
highest = maximum . map height
```

- `babyBlocks` : This function generates all possible blocks for the given block types (by rotating them), converts them into an initial tower set (by wrapping them into simple list with one element) and starts the convergence of the initial tower set into a final tower set.
- `possibleBlocks` : For a given set of block types, this function returns all possible blocks by rotating them. Strictly, there should be `3! = 6` rotations (all permutations of the three coordinates), but we only need to consider half of them because we can treat rotations with swapped widths and depths as duplicates.
- `canStack` : Checks if a given block can be placed onto another block.
- `expand` : For a given tower, the function checks all the available blocks if they can be put on the top of the tower. A new tower is created for each compatible block that can be put on top.
- `converge` : This function essentially repeats `expand` for a set of towers until no more block can be put on one of them. The solution must be the maximum height of the remaining towers.
- `height` : Returns the height of a given tower by summing up its block heights.
- `highest` : For a given set of towers, identifies the maximum height.

Comment: Please don't do `== []`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853922/null-instead-of